# Pulse Width Modulated (PWM) Spacecraft Attitude control

Tags: matlab, simulink, pwm, pid-controller

I'm trying to create an attitude control system in Simulink that can control the attitude of a spacecraft. The torque is created by a binary on/off pulse that is on for 't' seconds. I am using the below setup (Spacecraft Dynamics Block):

[image]

I want to use a PID controller of some sort that updates the attitude of the spacecraft to stabilize it with a fixed-value pulse that is on for a certain duration. How can I do this?